# IIS SMTP Configure Delivery Status Notification Content

Tags: iis, smtp, dsn

how can I configure IIS SMTP sever to not attach the original mail to the Delivery Status Notification messages? The problem is that when sending newsletters with fairly large attchemnts all these attachments are again attached to the DSN messages which results in a full administrator's mailbox.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To my knowlege: No way.